# Declaring global array that fetches value from DB in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a template that loads my view into parts like header, footer and main_content. I have a widget in the footer where i would like to display top 5 posts of a particular category, say "Current Affairs". Since the template is loaded in parts, i want a function that loads this data and provide it to the footer.php file of the template. However, this function should be loaded in the constructor so that all the other functions of the controller doesnt need to call this function. Heres my code.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

// public $data['latest_current_affairs'] = array(); // Tried this, doesnt work.

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Add');
    $this->load->model('Fetch');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('date');
    // $this->load_widgets(); //works fine if we print an array
}

public function load_widgets()
{
    $where = array('post_category' => "Current Affairs", 'post_status' => "Published");
    $orderby = NULL;
    $limit = 5;
    $data['latest_current_affairs'] = $this->Fetch->selectWhereLimit('post', $where, $orderby, $limit);     
    // print_r($data); //works fine if printed through here.
}

public function index()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'home';
    $this->load_widgets();
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    print_r($data); //Here the data prints only the main_content index but not the latest_current_affairs index of the array.
}}
```

Here's the content of my template.php:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

Any suggestions for code optimization or better coding techniques are welcome.

Comment: Why not you create helper for it and call your helper whenever you want.

Comment: well that would be a working option, but i'm curious about how do we make a global array and fetch values from the db.

Comment: apparently the data to be stored in the array is pretty huge and storing it in a session is a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample Code To store data in global array.

```
class Check extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['f1'] = $this->f1();
    }

    function f1()
    {
       return "response1";
    }

    function f2()
    {
       $this->data['f2'] = "response2";
       print_r($this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped very much... thanx ajith

Answer (score 1):

To declare globe array in codeigniter you have to define in your `config file`

```
$config['item_name']= array('post_category' => "Current Affairs", 'post_status' => "Published");
```

For fetching config item

```
$this->config->item('item_name');
```

So your index function would be

```
public function index()
{
    $where=$this->config->item('item_name');
    $orderby = NULL;
    $limit = 5;
    $data['latest_current_affairs'] = $this->Fetch->selectWhereLimit('post', $where, $orderby, $limit);    
    $data['main_content'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    print_r($data); //Here the data prints only the main_content index but not the latest_current_affairs index of the array.
}
```

**UPDATED**

You can create helper file for it

```
function load_widgets() 
{ 
$CI = get_instance(); 
$CI->load->model('Fetch'); 
$where=$CI->config->item('item_name'); 
$orderby = NULL; 
$limit = 5; 
return $latest_current_affairs = $CI->Fetch->selectWhereLimit('post', $where, $orderby, $limit); 
}
```

And you Controller

```
function __construct() 
{ 
parent::__construct(); 
$this->load->model('Add'); 
$this->load->model('Fetch'); 
$this->load->library('form_validation'); 
$this->load->helper('date'); 
$result=$this->load_widgets(); 
print_r($result); 
}
```

ans don't forget to call your helper file

Comment: you've written the contents of load_widgets() and then called that function again.

Comment: we should be able to call the function load_widgets() in the constructor, since many other functions require it to load automatically.

Comment: But i think it would be better if we create helper of it!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88149/discussion-between-cyberrspiritt-and-saty).

Comment: and this solution doesnt work... what i asked was to make the $data['latest_current_affairs'] array global for a single controller. what you did was made the where clause as global via config file